# Writing to console window not via stdout

Tags: c#, console, console-application

how can I write DIRECTLY into console, without bothering with stdout in c#? I'm upgrading some old program, which has it's stdout redirected into file (because the output matters), and I need somehow to write directly to console, and that the text won't appear in stdout. Is it possible (without using WinAPI)?

EDIT: I'm aware of the possibility to write to stderr, althrough, is it possible to set cursor position for stderr on console?

Comment: If your problem is just set cursor position have a look at --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx

Comment: Eh, my bad. I thought, that setting cursor position works just for Console.Write, nto for Console.Error.Write. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write to `Console.Error`, which, although it can be redirected, is separate from stdout.

> is it possible to set cursor position for stderr on console?

**Edit**: Assuming that stderr has not been redirected, see `Console.CursorTop` and `Console.CursorLeft`. There's [various other members on the `Console` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members.aspx) that you might find useful.

To answer your question directly, use the Win32 [`WriteConsole`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteConsole.html) function. As far as I can see, the .NET framework doesn't have methods for writing directly to the console window.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your program and redirect its StandardOutput and StandardError, what do you expect to happen to your writes when there is no console?

For this reason, the answer is likely “you can’t” (except perhaps by using crazy hacks, which probably involve Windows API which you said you didn’t want to use).

Think of the console window as nothing more than a UI element that allows the user to view the stdout/stderr of your program (and to provide stdin). It doesn’t really exist for any other purpose.

Comment: Curiously telnet.exe doesn't use stdout or stderr, yet still writes to the console. I'm yet to find out how!

Comment: Just for reference, telnet uses WriteConsoleOutputW and ReadConsoleInputA, to know more see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805785/why-cant-i-redirect-output-from-writeconsole

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up implementing the low level [WriteConsoleOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404(v=vs.85).aspx) some time ago as part of a terminal based Tetris implementation I wrote, since doing coloured console output with `Console.BackgroundColor` and `Console.Write`, is far too slow for full screen refreshes. Doing the raw buffer output is **much** faster.

Note, this writes text to a location on the screen (eg 5,10), but doesn't update or keep track of the cursor position on it's own - writing with this method will update the text buffer and display the output, but the cursor won't move. You'll need to move and keep track of the console cursor manually with some other method, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Here's my code:

Main interop class:

```
public static class LowLevelConsole {
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string fileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
        IntPtr securityAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,
        IntPtr template);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool WriteConsoleOutput(
      SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
      CharInfo[] lpBuffer,
      Coord dwBufferSize,
      Coord dwBufferCoord,
      ref SmallRect lpWriteRegion);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Coord {
        public short X;
        public short Y;

        public Coord(short X, short Y) {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct CharUnion {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public char UnicodeChar;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte AsciiChar;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct CharInfo {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CharUnion Char;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public ushort Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SmallRect {
        public short Left;
        public short Top;
        public short Right;
        public short Bottom;
    }


    [STAThread]
    public static void Write(string line, CharacterAttribute attribute, short xLoc, short yLoc) {
        SafeFileHandle h = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        short writeHeight = 1;
        short writeWidth = (short)line.Length;

        if (!h.IsInvalid) {
            CharInfo[] buf = new CharInfo[writeWidth * writeHeight];
            SmallRect rect = new SmallRect() { Left = xLoc, Top = yLoc, Right = (short)(writeWidth + xLoc), Bottom = (short)(writeHeight + yLoc) };

            for (int i = 0; i < writeWidth; i++) {
                buf[i].Attributes = (ushort)attribute;
                buf[i].Char.UnicodeChar = line[i];
            }

            bool b = WriteConsoleOutput(h, buf, new Coord() { X = writeWidth, Y = writeHeight }, new Coord() { X = 0, Y = 0 }, ref rect);
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static bool WriteBuffer(CharInfo[,] buffer) { // returns true of success
        SafeFileHandle h = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!h.IsInvalid) {
            short BufferWidth = (short)buffer.GetLength(0);
            short BufferHeight = (short)buffer.GetLength(1);
            CharInfo[] buf = new CharInfo[BufferWidth * BufferHeight];
            SmallRect rect = new SmallRect() { Left = 0, Top = 0, Right = BufferWidth, Bottom = BufferHeight };


            for (int y = 0; y < BufferHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < BufferWidth; x++) {
                    buf[y * BufferWidth + x] = buffer[x, y];
                }
            }
            return WriteConsoleOutput(h, buf, new Coord() { X = BufferWidth, Y = BufferHeight }, new Coord() { X = 0, Y = 0 }, ref rect);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Character attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
[Flags]
public enum CharacterAttribute : ushort {
    FOREGROUND_BLUE = 0x0001,
    FOREGROUND_GREEN = 0x0002,
    FOREGROUND_RED = 0x0004,
    FOREGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0008,
    BACKGROUND_BLUE = 0x0010,
    BACKGROUND_GREEN = 0x0020,
    BACKGROUND_RED = 0x0040,
    BACKGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0080,
    COMMON_LVB_LEADING_BYTE = 0x0100,
    COMMON_LVB_TRAILING_BYTE = 0x0200,
    COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL = 0x0400,
    COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL = 0x0800,
    COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL = 0x1000,
    COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO = 0x4000,
    COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE = 0x8000
}
```

Test code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // write to location 0,0
        LowLevelConsole.Write("Some test text", CharacterAttribute.BACKGROUND_BLUE | CharacterAttribute.FOREGROUND_RED, 0, 0);
        // write to location 5,10
        LowLevelConsole.Write("another test at a different location", 
            CharacterAttribute.FOREGROUND_GREEN | CharacterAttribute.FOREGROUND_BLUE,
            5, 10);
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }
}
```